# jQuery promises with summernote hints

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, summernote

I am working on getting a live user list from a database for the [Summernote Hints](http://summernote.org/examples/#hint-for-mention) however when using async it just falls over, however with async off it causes the UI to freeze... clearly not optimal for the UX.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.editor').summernote({
        height: 300,
        hint: {
            match: /\B@(\w*)$/,
            users: function(keyword) {

                var result = data;

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/users/' + keyword,
                    type: 'get',
                    async: false //This works but freezes the UI
                }).done(function(data)
                {
                    result = data; //Set the result to the returned json array
                });

                return result;
            },
            search: function (keyword, callback) {
                callback(this.users(keyword)); //callback must be an array
            },
            content: function (item) {
                return '@' + item;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

How can I get async to work without falling over? I believe it has something to do with promises however not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call `callback`. `users` needs to call that from the `done` function.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.editor').summernote({
        height: 300,
        hint: {
            match: /\B@(\w*)$/,
            users: function(keyword, callback) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/users/' + keyword,
                    type: 'get',
                    async: true //This works but freezes the UI
                }).done(callback);
            },
            search: function (keyword, callback) {
                this.users(keyword, callback); //callback must be an array
            },
            content: function (item) {
                return '@' + item;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `callback` is a function, in your answer there isn't one.

Comment: @Ian i just pass it to `done` and let `done` call it.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed the callback in the users function, thanks! Works like a charm. I can't accept your answer for another few minutes.