# Summernote get mentions from php

Tags: jquery, arrays, summernote, hint

I am using Summernote editor with mentions (@username). (https://summernote.org/examples/#hint-for-mention)
I am looking for a way to load the array of usernames into Summernote.
What I've tried: (with help from [jQuery promises with summernote hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883780/jquery-promises-with-summernote-hints))

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.editor').summernote({
        height: 300,
        hint: {
             match: /\B@(\w*)$/,
             users: function(keyword, callback) {
                 $.ajax({
                     url: '{path}/get_users/' + keyword,
                     type: 'get',
                     async: true
                 }).done(callback);
             },
             search: function (keyword, callback) {
                 this.users(keyword, callback);
             },
             content: function (item) {
                 return '@' + item;
             }
       });
   });
});
```

The PHP that returns the array of usernames:

```
public function get_users($keyword='')
{
    $ar = array('jayden', 'sam', 'alvin', 'david');
    echo json_encode($ar); // returns ['jayden', 'sam', 'alvin', 'david']
}
```

The result:

```
Uncaught TypeError: items.map is not a function
    at HintPopover.createItemTemplates (summernote.js:7625)
    at Object.<anonymous> (summernote.js:7672)
    at i (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
```

It seems like this.users is not recognised as an Array... 
Thank you for your advice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare in your `ajax` call that the return type is `json`.

```
users: function(keyword, callback) {
             $.ajax({
                 url: '{path}/get_users/' + keyword,
                 type: 'get',
                 dataType: "json",   <----here
                 async: true
             }).done(callback);
         },
```